# How to call methods dynamically?

Tags: javascript

How can one call methods which are stored in an object literal?

How can one select these properties dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the variable like normal. Just pass it to `hasOwnProperty`, and then use it just like you did the `key` variable for the property lookup.

```
if (Mo[key].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    Mo[key][property]();
}
```

But since you're assuming the property will be a function, then a `typeof` test may be safer.

```
if (typeof Mo[key][property] === "function") {
    Mo[key][property]();
}
```

Comment: I've also heard to use `str1 = Object.prototype.toString.call(arg)` to detect object types...didn't know which one to use...

Comment: @pure_code: That's a good solution for certain types, but it's very slow compared to `typeof`. For functions, `typeof` is safe to use. Some very old versions of Chrome would report a regex as a function, but that has long since been resolved.